# Problema em código de snake game

Tags: javascript

Depois de aprender JavaScript, criei um desafio para mim mesmo: refazer o "jogo da cobrinha". Porém, estou com um problema: quero que, quando a cobra passe pela comida, a comida mude de lugar, porém ela continua no mesmo lugar.

```js
//canvas
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightgreen";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //variaveis
    let grid = 20;
    let size = 5;
    let directions = [];
    //cobra
    let head = {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
    };
    let tail = {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
    };
    //comida
    let food = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * grid) * grid,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * grid) * grid,
    };
    //função principal
    function main(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                head.x--;
                directions.push('left');
                break;
            case 38:
                head.y--;
                directions.push('up');
                break;
            case 39:
                head.x++;
                directions.push('right');
                break;
            case 40:
                head.y++;
                directions.push('down');
                break;
        };
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, grid, grid);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillRect(head.x * grid, head.y * grid, grid, grid);
        if (directions.length >= size) {        
            ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgreen';
            ctx.fillRect(tail.x * grid, tail.y * grid, grid, grid);
            switch (directions.shift()) {
                case 'left':
                    tail.x--;
                    break;
                case 'up':
                    tail.y--;
                    break;
                case 'right':
                    tail.x++
                    break;
                case 'down':
                    tail.y++;
                    break;
            };
        };
        if (head.x == food.x && head.y == food.y) {
            food.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid) * grid;
            food.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid) * grid;   
        };
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', main);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Jogo da cobrinha</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Tomás Ricardo" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Tomás, se colocar um `console.log(head.x, food.x, head.y, food.y);` antes da IF vai notar que os valores de X e Y de ambos são totalmente diferentes. E o problema dessa diferença de localizações é devido a como vc adicionou os objetos: `ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, grid, grid);` `ctx.fillRect(head.x * grid, head.y * grid, grid, grid);`

Comment: Boa tarde, Tomás. Não adicione "[Resolvido]" no título da pergunta. Caso alguma resposta tenha solucionado seu problema, apenas marque a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce fez uma multiplicacao desnecessaria para o valor de `food` com o `grid` em:

```
let food = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * grid) * grid,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * grid) * grid,
    };
```

isso faz com que os valores de `head.x` `head.y` sejam sempre diferentes de `food.x` e `food.y`. Remova a segunda multiplicaco, deixe assim:

```
let food = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * grid),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * grid),
      };
```

Voce esqueceu de multiplicar por `grid` na funcao `ctx.fillRect` em :

```
ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, grid, grid);
```

coloque assim:

```
ctx.fillRect(food.x * grid, food.y * grid, grid, grid);
```

e la no seu `if`, remova a multiplicacao extra do `grid`:

```
if (head.x == food.x && head.y == food.y) {
          food.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid) * grid;
          food.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid) * grid;
        }
```

Fica assim:

```
if (head.x == food.x && head.y == food.y) {
          food.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid);
          food.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid);
        }
```

Agora os valores de `head` e `food` irao se igualar em algum momento e entao a posicao do `food` ira mudar(veja o `console.log()`). Segue o codigo completo(execute e veja o resultado esperado é este):

```js
//canvas
      const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgreen';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      //variaveis
      let grid = 20;
      let size = 5;
      let directions = [];
      //cobra
      let head = {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
      };
      let tail = {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
      };
      //comida
      let food = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * grid),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * grid),
      };
      //função principal
      function main(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 37:
            head.x--;
            directions.push('left');
            break;
          case 38:
            head.y--;
            directions.push('up');
            break;
          case 39:
            head.x++;
            directions.push('right');
            break;
          case 40:
            head.y++;
            directions.push('down');
            break;
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(food.x * grid, food.y * grid, grid, grid);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillRect(head.x * grid, head.y * grid, grid, grid);
        if (directions.length >= size) {
          ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgreen';
          ctx.fillRect(tail.x * grid, tail.y * grid, grid, grid);
          switch (directions.shift()) {
            case 'left':
              tail.x--;
              break;
            case 'up':
              tail.y--;
              break;
            case 'right':
              tail.x++;
              break;
            case 'down':
              tail.y++;
              break;
          }
        }
        // console.log(food, head);
        if (head.x == food.x && head.y == food.y) {
          food.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid);
          food.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid);
        }
      }
      document.addEventListener('keydown', main);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Jogo da cobrinha</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Tomás Ricardo" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```